# て-form of いる in compound sentence

Tags: て-form

In English, we can say, "Brad Pitt is living in Los Angeles and is a famous actor". I wrote this sentence as two Japanese sentences.

> ブラッド・ピットはロサンゼルスに住んでいます。有名な俳優です。
>
> Brad Pitt is living in Los Angeles. He is a famous actor.

Can いる be written in て-form to give the following compound sentence? Or is it best to just use the two sentences above?

> ブラッド・ピットはロサンゼルスに住んでいて、有名な俳優です。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your second sentence sounds better than your first, but it still lacks the conciseness that many readers require in writing.

The even more concise and less lengthy way to say it is to use a relative clause.

> 「ブラッド・ピットはロサンゼルスに[住]{す}んでいる[有名]{ゆうめい}な[俳優]{はいゆう}です。」
>
> = "Brad Pitt is a well-known actor who lives in L.A."

(Whether it is "to live" or "to be living", it is 「住んでいる」 in Japanese.)